# ReactJS: Do CSS Modules provide any benefit when using SCSS or SASS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I started learning React and got to the part where they explain how CSS Modules are useful to automatically create class names that will not collide between components.

But when using SCSS or SASS we can wrap all the code in a "Component" class making anything under it unique to that component, for example, if you have this SCSS file:

```
.Person {
    .enabled {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

The "enabled" class will only get applied to elements inside the Person component (assuming you assigned the "Person" class to your component)

So, does this make CSS Modules useless? Or is there any other benefit of using CSS modules when also using SCSS and SASS?

Many thanks

Comment: In before this gets closed. Use styled-components ... Thank me later

Comment: Not sure why you think it will get closed, I believe is a valid question and many people don't want to write all their CSS inside the javascript, making everything more cluttered.

Comment: The advantage is only if the same design is shared between an application that is not done only with React. The styles can be reused across the frameworks.

Comment: Because it had 2 votes to close within seconds... But to answer your question, no I don't think it negates CSS Modules, the main purpose of CSS Modules is to generate, as close to, a unique class name so styles can be locally scoped. Defining the class name as you have done is a manual effort, the very thing CSS Modules is designed to mitigate the need to try and do. Also, styled-components !== clutter. You can split your style components into separate files as well, you can do pretty much everything SCSS and CSS Modules can do plus more.

Answer (score 1):

CSS-in-JS techniques have two main advantages:

- You can keep the CSS for a component together with the component
- You can **distribute** that CSS with the component if you reuse it across projects

Comment: Thanks for your reply Quentin, but I was not asking about writing the CSS inside the Javascript like with Inline Styles, Radium or Styled-Components.
Instead, my question was referring to using CSS modules vs using SASS or SCSS. In both cases the CSS is written in a separate file.